# Django много форм на одной странице с одинаковыми name

Tags: python, django

Всем привет. Не понимаю как я могу объяснить ситуация чтобы было понятно. Но у меня есть форма обернутая в for, из за этого получается много форм на странице и всегда разное количество. Пример:

```
{% for match in matches %}
<form method="post" ...>
    <div ...> {{ match.title }} </div>
    <input name="a" value="a" ...>
    <button type="submit" ...> Press </button>
</form>
{% endfor %}
```

Как мне в View при вызове `if request.method == 'POST'` вызывать определенную форму?

Answer (score 0):

Нужно каким-то способом знать, в какой форме пользователь нажал `submit`.

Это может быть либо разные URL-ы и соответственно функции view на сервере (которые дальше могут вызывать одну и ту же функцию обработки с параметром, который будет идентифицировать форму). Или это может дополнительный `hidden` параметр в самой форме:

```
<input type="hidden" name="form-id" value="{{ тут какой-то идентификатор формы, вероятно из match }}">
```

Во `view` можно смотреть на этот параметр (`request.POST.get('form-id')`) и таким образом знать, какую форму прислал клиент.